# Partially Tokenizing strings in Java with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, string

I have a variable of the form abc_xyz_pqr_def and I want to derive only the abc_xyz_pqr part of it. Is there any easy way to achieve this using java.

Comment: please give some more detail. what can be possible values of the variable and what is the criteria to derive substring

Comment: SO is the kind of site where when you're having a problem trying to do something, the community try give you an hint or a solution. But, at least you have to write few lines of code.

Comment: [regex for that](https://regex101.com/r/2qzjol/1)

Comment: @nilesh: The variable is of integer type. I would like to know if java has something inbuilt already to achieve such an operation. thanks!

Comment: @Amruth you have to include the correct problem the correct example in your question, so can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `"abc_xyz_pqr_def"` is a string representing the contents of a variable, and not the name of the variable, it looks like you're going to have to use Regular expressions here. Unless "pqr" or "_def" will always be the same, in which case you can set "_def" as your delimiter. ex:`var.split("_def");` will return an array with the string `"abc_xyz_pqr"` in it.